# Stats on file creation in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Whenever I create (or even update it seems) a file in OSX I get the following dialog:

```
    ➜  hello touch test.txt
test.txt Stats {
  dev: 16777220,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 252423193,
  size: 0,
  blocks: 0,
  atimeMs: 1502219299000,
  mtimeMs: 1502219299000,
  ctimeMs: 1502219299000,
  birthtimeMs: 1502219299000,
  atime: 2017-08-08T19:08:19.000Z,
  mtime: 2017-08-08T19:08:19.000Z,
  ctime: 2017-08-08T19:08:19.000Z,
  birthtime: 2017-08-08T19:08:19.000Z }
```

I generally use `ohmyzsh`, but I've tried using my vanilla bash shell and it does the same thing. I can't seem to figure out what is causing it. Any ideas?

Comment: If you create a clean new account (or log into the automatically-reset-on-logout Guest account), so you have a clean unmodified bash environment, does the same problem happen?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why. It's because my `touch` command was overwritten by `touch` from `npm`. I figured it out by doing `which touch` which returned `/usr/local/bin/touch` instead of `/usr/bin/touch`. `/usr/local/bin/touch` was then symlinked to `touch` in `yarn`'s global `node_modules`.